# regex to extract numbers starting from second symbol

Tags: javascript, regex

Sorry for one more to the tons of regexp questions but I can't find anything similar to my needs. I want to output the string which can contain number or letter 'A' as the first symbol and numbers only on other positions. Input is any string, for example:

```
---INPUT---    -OUTPUT-
A123asdf456 -> A123456
0qw#$56-398 -> 056398
B12376B6f90 -> 12376690
12A12345BCt -> 1212345
```

What I tried is `replace(/[^A\d]/g, '')` (I use JS), which almost does the job except the case when there's `A` in the middle of the string. I tried to use `^` anchor but then the pattern doesn't match other numbers in the string. Not sure what is easier - extract matching characters or remove unmatching.

Comment: Have you considered doing this in two steps? Check if `input[0] === 'A'` and just keep the numbers, sticking an `'A'` back on the front if the check found one?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol yes, I did think about it (also about the loop w/o regex at all) but I'm really interested how to do that using regex in one step.

Comment: @donwvoters - why? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match and capture desired and undesired characters within two different sides of an alternation, then replace those undesired with nothing:

```
^(A)|\D
```

JS code:

```js
var inputStrings = [
    "A-123asdf456",
    "A123asdf456",
    "0qw#$56-398",
    "B12376B6f90",
    "12A12345BCt"
];
console.log(
    inputStrings.map(v => v.replace(/^(A)|\D/g, "$1"))
);
```

Comment: Please check update. This is much more cleaner and shorter to what you are using. @skwisgaar

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do it like this using a negative lookahead and then replace with an empty string.

In an non capturing group `(?:`, use a negative lookahad `(?!` to assert that what follows is not the beginning of the string followed by `^A` or a digit `\d`. If that is the case, match any character `.`

[`(?:(?!^A|\d).)+`](https://regex101.com/r/vW9hWN/1)

```js
var pattern = /(?:(?!^A|\d).)+/g;
var strings = [
  "A123asdf456",
  "0qw#$56-398",
  "B12376B6f90",
  "12A12345BCt"

];

for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
  console.log(strings[i] + " ==> " + strings[i].replace(pattern, ""));
}
```

Comment: Good, but I think the 0 is unnecessary since it is included in the `\d`. `(?:(?!^[A]|\d).)+` should do the job.

Comment: @LuisGuzman Nice one! I have updated my answer to `(?:(?!^A|\d).)+`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex : [`/(^A)?\d+/g`](https://regex101.com/r/DPwQcW/1)

```js
var arr = ['A123asdf456','0qw#$56-398','B12376B6f90','12A12345BCt', 'A-123asdf456'],
    result = arr.map(s => s.match(/(^A|\d)/g).join(''));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Note that this uses `match`, not `replace` - important difference there :D

Comment: It's pretty close but breaks on the `A-123asdf456` string (initial 'A' is missing)